# How to display image on gridview when image path get from database

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

can anybody please guide me how to display an image on gridview in asp.net?
i had the image path get from database, eg : D:\Picture\photo.jpg

i had try this but it appear nothing in the image box.
my front-end code:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="id" HeaderText="Email ID" Visible="False">
         <HeaderStyle  />
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="photo_url" HeaderText="Photo" Visible="false">
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height = "100" Width = "100" runat="server" DataImageUrlField = '<%# Eval("photo_url") %>' /> >>>>>>>>display image on this part
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="post_body" HeaderText="Post"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="post_id" HeaderText="Comment/Post ID" Visible="False">
        <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
    </asp:BoundColumn>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Did you get an error? Did the correct URL appear in the resulting HTML?

Comment: it is did not appear any error but when run it the image was not appear in the image column, just an empty column. the path get from database for photo_url is correct. it is D:\Projects\Orlig_FB_Service\Images\wall_post_551183598322481_10152973356489762.jpg

Comment: Yes, I know, you said that in your question. Did the correct URL appear in the resulting HTML? If you navigate to that URL manually, does the image appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace with this one:

> ```
>   <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height = "100" Width = "100" runat="server" 
>              ImageUrl='<%# ResolveUrl(Eval("photo_url").ToString()) %>' />
> ```

Comment: thanks for your response, i tried it before but the same results comes out. Blank at the image column. if i hard-code the image url like this, `ImageUrl='D:\Picture\photo.jpg'` the image was appear, it is means do not hv any prob with the path

Comment: Ok, you need to have a relative path, so you need to check the value of photo_url in your database first. you need to make sure that the value format is look like this: `~/Picture/photo.jpg` also make sure that you have the folder under your project solution